# SQL comparison within max function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a list of 20 events grouped by their Ids and sorted by whether they are in progress, pending, or already finished. The problem is that there are events with the same id that include finished, pending, and in progress events and I want to have 20 distinct Ids in the end. What I want to do is group these events together but if one of them is in progress then sort that group by that event. So basically I want to sort by the latest end time that is also before now().

What I have so far is something like this where end and start are end/start times. I'm not sure if what is inside max() is behaving how I should expect.

```
select * from event_schedule as t1 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(event_id) as e 
    from event_schedule 
    GROUP BY event_id 
    order by MAX(end < unix_timestamp(now())) asc, 
             MIN(start >= unix_timestamp(now())) asc, 
             MAX(start) desc 
             limit 0, 20 
    ) 
    as t2 on (t1.event_id = t2.e)
```

This results in some running / pending events to be mixed around in order when I want them to be in the order running -> pending -> Ended.

Comment: Did the answer below suit your needs? Could you leave a comment and/or accept it if it was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first create a view in order to not get an overcomplicated `SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE VIEW v_event_schedule AS 
SELECT *,
       CASE
          WHEN end < unix_timestamp(now())
            THEN 1
          WHEN start > unix_timestamp(now())
            THEN 2
            ELSE 3
       END AS category
FROM   event_schedule;
```

This view *v_event_schedule* returns an extra column, in addition to the columns of *event_schedule*, which represents the priority of the category (running, pending, past):

1. running (in progress)
2. pending (future)
3. past

Then the following will do what you want:

```
SELECT     a.*
FROM       v_event_schedule a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT   id,
                     MIN(category) category 
            FROM     v_event_schedule b
            GROUP BY id
           ) b
        ON a.id = b.id
       AND a.category = b.category
ORDER BY   category,
           start DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

The `ORDER BY` can be further adapted to your needs as to how you want to sort within the same category. I added `start DESC` as that seemed what you were doing in your attempt.

#### About the original `ORDER BY`

You had this:

```
order by MAX(end < unix_timestamp(now())) asc, 
         MIN(start >= unix_timestamp(now())) asc,
```

The expressions you have there evaluate to boolean values, and both elements in the `ORDER BY` each divide the groups into two sections, one for `false` and one for `true`, so in total 4 groups.

The first of the two will order IDs first that have no record with an *end* value in the past, because only then the boolean expression is always `false` which is the only way to make the `MAX` of them `false` as well.

Now let's say for the same ID you have both records that have an *end* date in the future as well as records with an *end* date in the past. In that case the `MAX` aggregates to `true`, and so the *id* will be sorted secondary. This is not intended, as this ID might have a "running" record.

I did not look into making your query work based on such aggregates on boolean expressions. It requires some time to understand what they are doing. A `CASE WHEN` to determine the category with a number really makes the SQL a lot easier to understand, at least to me.